# In a VS Code extension, how can I be notified when the user cuts/copies/or pastes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For my extension I need to know when a cut/copy/paste happens and be able to get the text associated with those operations. I can probably get the text from the editor if I know *when* they happen.

I cannot find a listener for these operations. I suppose I can look for ctrl-x, ctrl-c, and ctrl-v keyboard inputs but some users may use the edit menu and not use the keyboard.

Is there a way to be notified when these operations happen either from the keyboard or the edit menu?

Answer (score 3):

Original asker here...

I came up with a solution that involves overriding the default cut/copy/paste actions in the editor. Here is the code for 'copy' in extension.js (I am using js not ts):

```
//override the editor.action.clipboardCopyAction with our own
var clipboardCopyDisposable = vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand('editor.action.clipboardCopyAction', overriddenClipboardCopyAction); 

context.subscriptions.push(clipboardCopyDisposable);

/*
 * Function that overrides the default copy behavior. We get the selection and use it, dispose of this registered
 * command (returning to the default editor.action.clipboardCopyAction), invoke the default one, and then re-register it after the default completes
 */
function overriddenClipboardCopyAction(textEditor, edit, params) {

    //debug
    console.log("---COPY TEST---");

    //use the selected text that is being copied here
    getCurrentSelectionEvents(); //not shown for brevity

    //dispose of the overridden editor.action.clipboardCopyAction- back to default copy behavior
    clipboardCopyDisposable.dispose();

    //execute the default editor.action.clipboardCopyAction to copy
    vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.clipboardCopyAction").then(function(){

        console.log("After Copy");

        //add the overridden editor.action.clipboardCopyAction back
        clipboardCopyDisposable = vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand('editor.action.clipboardCopyAction', overriddenClipboardCopyAction);

        context.subscriptions.push(clipboardCopyDisposable);
    }); 
}
```

This definitely doesn't *feel* like the best solution... however it does seem to work. Any comments/suggestions? Are there any issues that repeatedly registering and unregistering will cause?

Answer (score 1):

There is no api to access the clipboard directly but some extensions override the default copy and paste shortcuts to customize the copy paste behavior. Here are two examples:

- https://github.com/aefernandes/vscode-clipboard-history-extension/blob/master/src/clipboard.ts
- https://github.com/stef-levesque/vscode-multiclip/blob/master/src/extension.ts

As you note, that approach will not work when copying using the context menu however. For supporting that as well, you could try intercepting the `editor.action.clipboardCopyAction` command. See how the Vim extension intercepts the `type` command for an example of this: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/aa8d9549ac0d31b393a9346788f9a9a93187c222/extension.ts#L208

Comment: Yes, this would work for me. Are you aware of any documentation for overrideCommand()? 

I would need to still perform the default behavior perhaps with: vscode.commands.executeCommand("default:editor.action.clipboardPaste‌​Action"); ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposed api in v1.68 for intercepting and modifying pastes.  Since it is proposed for now you can only test it in the Insiders Build.

See [copy/paste proposed extension api](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_68.md#copy-paste-api):

> The new `documentPaste` API proposal lets extensions hook into copy
> and paste inside text editors. This can be used to modify the text
> that is inserted on paste. Your extension can also store metadata when
> text copy and use this metadata when pasting (for example for bringing
> along imports when pasting between two code files).
>
> The [document paste extension
> sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/document-paste)
> shows this API in action:   <-long code example in the release notes->

Here is the actual (brief) api: [proposed documentPaste api](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.documentPaste.d.ts)

See also [using a proposed api](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api.md#:%7E:text=Proposed%20API%20is%20a%20set%20of%20unstable%20API,distribution%20and%20cannot%20be%20used%20in%20published%20extensions.)