# Where to find vscode undo stack documentation

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to develop a vscode extension that needs to access the vscode undo stack but I can't seem to find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not see any way for extensions to directly access the undo stack.  The undo stack is implemented in [`editStack.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/common/model/editStack.ts), but it isn't exposed in the API.

I also do not see any [open issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+undo+api) requesting such access.  I didn't search through closed issues though.

#### Some possible alternatives

The question [How to see local history changes in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446901/how-to-see-local-history-changes-in-visual-studio-code) discusses a couple of extensions that provide access to old versions by keeping track themselves.

When invoking [`TextEditor.edit`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor.edit), you have the option of creating undo stops before and after.

Via [`executeCommand`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#commands.executeCommand), it is possible to execute commands like `undo`, `redo`, and `cursorUndo`.

You can use [`workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument) to monitor documents for changes in order to collect your own document history.  However, it does not look like you can tell whether a given change also created an undo stop, nor whether the change was triggered by an undo or redo command.

That said, [Issue #1431: Support onDidExecuteCommand](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1431), discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57731838/2659307) of mine, should allow listening for invocation of `undo` and `redo`, but I haven't played with it at all.

Comment: Hey @Scott McPeak. Great Info here. And the options we have when invoking [`TextEditor.edit`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor.edit)  `{undoStopAfter: false, undoStopBefore: false}` works for my purpose and can disable the undo.